# how to add html text with custom background and border

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. I just bought a theme for it that does not support custom.css by default. I do not want to mess around with the default files as i am not a techie. I had previously done this by simple making a custom blockquote.

So what i want to do is add a custom background, with a border, to the text on my pages:

- I want the background to be plain black with 60% transparency
- I want an image as the border, only on the left side, which repeats.
- Keep bit of padding on all sides so that text doesn't reach the corners.
- The text should be white in color with any font and size.

I have been looking all over the net and been trying this for quite some time with no results. **How can I create this custom border/background?**

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom css file and then just import it in the default file?

@import url(url of your custom css)

Editted from Erics Post:

```
.example {
  /* Set Background Black 60% opacity */
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  /*Text Color */
  color: "#FFF";
  /* Text-padding */
  padding: 5px;
  /*Border creation */
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat ;
  border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat ;
```

}

If you are just trying to have a border down the side of your page that contains other elements you should look at position or floating a div. Please also note that if IE is an important browser to you these setting will not work.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more in detail. how do i create the custom.css and where do i add the import command?

Comment: You can create a custom css file using any text editor. The css listed by Eric is a great start for what you are trying to do (although assumin you will be calling this on multiple elements change the "#" to a ".". Then at the top of the default css file just add @import url("path to your custom file") obivously substituting path to your custom file with the actual path. You would then add this custom css class ( to your div or other element).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a head start on how to style the custom border and background:

```
#example {
    border-width: 12px;
    -moz-border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat ;
    border-image:url("border-image") 12 repeat ;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/HBzQm/

Comment: i just added a custom css plugin. its quiet easy to handle for non-tehcies like me.
and i added the code you provided. it did most of the stuff that i required flawlessly. but there are still issues. can you help me fix them please

Comment: heres how the code looks as of now

blockquote p {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  color: "white";
  padding: 5px;
  /*Border creation */
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image:url("http://deviant-gaming.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mbt-2_00000_1.png") 30 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image:url("http://deviant-gaming.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mbt-2_00000_1.png") 30 repeat;
  border-image:url("http://deviant-gaming.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mbt-2_00000_1.png") 30 repeat;
}
and heres how the it shows up
http://gyazo.com/745af84fdae4fac26a81e0d72ddcd519

Comment: the problem is that the there is weird white color stuff on the right corner (something like a broken border).
and even though the blockquote doesnt end, the background breaks at every paragraph. 
the border on the left side is getting overlapped. its not repeating properly